# link jumps one line after being clicked

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink, wordpress-gutenberg

I just built this website for a client with Wordpress and gutenberg blocks but the links are jumping one line down after clicking. I tried giving them `display:inline`, but nothing works. I can't find the problem so before I'm going completely insane, I thought I'd ask you guys. You an see the jump on the right side under "Features" [here](https://samirafreitag.com/publikationen/)

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

On `focus` and `active` status, your theme applies `display:block` on `a` tag, in result your link behaviour changes when you click and focus on it.

You can add this custom css to solve this issue:

```
a:focus,
a:active {
    display: initial;
}
```